# MySQL performance degradation

Tags: mysql, performance

- Centos 6.3, mysql 5.7 with default configuration without tuning, CPU 2.4 64 bits vmware, RAM 10GB, HDD 500GB

The server was working fine with 4 processes running at the same time making extensive insert each one in different table, after some days instead of 4 I used 12 processes to make some jobs (1 table for each process and around 42 million registers expected per table which corresponds to 1 month), when I check in the morning the process were still running and each table (of 12) had around 600000 registers a big let down to me, I stopped it then when I started it nothing it failed after some try it started, since then the behavior had changed completely, the insertion speed for ten minutes was 81000 register per 10 minutes while in another small server I get 1.4 millions per 10 minutes.

So I tried almost every tuning tip nothing happened with MyIsam and innoDB.

Fellows any recommendation is very welcome this is driving me crazy, I am waiting for you comment before deleting all data and re-install it  maybe this will not solve the problem I ma not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like the keys are causing troubles.  It is usually faster to disable keys and foreign keys while loading, then enable them.  The enabling will take a while because it is building the indexes.  However, doing it this way is faster than building them on the fly.

innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 7G for your 10GB 'machine'.

How are you doing the "load"?  LOAD DATA?  INSERT one row at a time (really slow)?  Batched INSERTs?